# Force Oracle SQL query to return at least one row when using GROUP BY

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

Using an empty grouping set, Oracle will not return any rows even when using aggregate functions.

For example, this query without a `GROUP BY` clause:

```
select count(*)
from dual
where 1 = 0;
```

yields:

```
  COUNT(*)
----------
         0
```

whereas this query with `GROUP BY ()`:

```
select count(*)
from dual
where 1 = 0
group by ();
```

doesn't return any rows.

How can I force Oracle to return at least one row, even when the query contains a `GROUP BY` clause?

Can it be done with `GROUPING SETS`, `ROLLUP`, `CUBE` or some other `GROUP BY` clause?

I would like to avoid using `UNION ALL`.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  You seem to understand how to get an aggregation query to return a result.  You have to be sure there is at least one row being aggregated.

Comment: I thought `GROUP BY ROLLUP (...)` (or something like that) would _always_ return at least one row (the "grand total", with a `COUNT(*)` of 0). Now, I know my assumptions where incorrect. Thank you!

Comment: . . Any group by modifier can be used to increase the number of rows.  But, you will still get the summary rows along with the original rows.  That doesn't seem to be what you want.

Comment: Those two queries both return a row for me, on 18c and 19c. What version are you using?

Comment: I am using 12c (12.1). This means that, with respect to `GROUP BY ()`, Oracle 18c and 19c are [compliant with the SQL standard](https://blog.jooq.org/2018/05/25/how-to-group-by-nothing-in-sql/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a CTE and check if the `group by` returns no rows:

```
with g as (
      select . . .
      from . . .
      group by . . .
     )
select g.*
from g
union all
select g.*
from (select 1 as n from dual) n left join
     g
     on 1 = 0  -- never true
where not exists (select 1 from g)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write the conditional aggregation without any `WHERE` clause in the query as follows:

```
SQL> select sum(case when 1 = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as res
  2    from dual
  3  group by 1;

       RES
----------
         0

SQL>
```